# Set Default Deployment Target in multi-device-hybrid-apps

Tags: ios, targets, visual-studio-cordova

I am developing an ios App and when i try to distiribute the app, I am facing following error:

```
Deployment Target is 6.0.0  but it needs 7.0.0
```

How can i set that the deployement target?

Comment: Isn t cordova javascript and not node.js?

Comment: Are you trying to deploy app to iPhone 6.0? Post detail about the device and output window text.

Comment: I use Visual Studio and try to build the project via a Remote Agent on my Mac Machine. It will be an Ipad 7.1 but that doesnt matter cause the error occurs when i try to build the project.

Comment: Could you please post details including text from the output window?